# Featherlight Lightbox JS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

Im implementing Featherlight's Lightbox in my WP theme.[here's the Github page for anybody interested](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#featherlight-gallery) Seems like a really nice lightbox right? (if you guys advice any others, please let me know.

I enqueued all css & js files nicely in my functions.php and it works. in the documentation is stated that I can create galleries by adding this in my theme.js (for example):

```
$('a.gallery').featherlightGallery({
  gallery: {
    previous: '«',
    next: '»',
    fadeIn: 300
  },
  openSpeed: 300
});
```

This should mean that every `a` on a page with the class `gallery` will be combined into a clickable lightbox gallery, cool! however when I do this, my Owl-carousel breaks[I embedded this beautiful slider](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)  in my theme as well and would like to use this slider in combination with the lightbox!

What I found out so far:

1. When the code above is not included in my js file, Owl carousel has the following classes assigned: `owl-carousel owl-theme owl-responsive-1199 owl-loaded` note the `owl-loaded`
2. When the code above **is** included in my js file, the owl carousel only has the class `owl-carousel`, meaning is it hidden, and not loaded. It is there in my DOM, but it does not show up due to the missing classes.

I have no idea what's causing this and what else to tell you guys. I can understand you have more questions, so please ask so I can give you more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are about to initialize the featherlight plugin on images contained by the owl slider, I think the problem will be in the timing.

Check out [this pen](http://codepen.io/dannystyle/full/tsrdL)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var carousel = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
  });

  $('a.gallery').featherlightGallery({
    gallery: {
      previous: '«',
      next: '»',
      fadeIn: 300
    },
    openSpeed: 300
  });  

});
```

On the pen I have loaded both owl-carousel.min.js, feather.min.js and feather.gallery.min.js because as it says " Gallery is just a plugin for this plugin" ( Hehe, pluginception )..

So you steps:

1. Make sure you already have loaded all of assets
2. Check your js if it could find the .gallery class links
3. If not, lets fix it.
4. Customize for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I had the Featherlight js **above** the Owl carousel JS, that was the issue somehow. I changed the order and now they work together as expected.... Thanks! Any idea how this is an issue?

Comment: You are welcome. By the way thanks for let me know these plugins :)

Comment: You're welcome as well :-) I found featherlight not to be to best option for me at the end. I'm now working with the Blueimp gallery, the look and functionality is awesome! check it out here: https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery and the gallery extension: https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery